# org-mode: Remove loading message when exporting HTML and then converting to PDF

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html, pdf

My goal is to export an HTML document and convert it to a PDF so I can have some of the advanced syntax highlighting and source code background coloring options in a PDF file.

It seems to be working well except for I get the following message at the bottom of the converted PDF document:

```
Loading [Contrib]/a11y/accessibility-menu.js
```

Is there a way I can remove this from the PDF document?  I have tried setting html-postamble to nil but that did not help. Also, I am using [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to convert the HTML to PDF. However, I have also tried several online converters and they all turn out the same. Here is what the message looks like on the PDF[image: message]

Here are the contents of the org file when the loading message appears:

```
#+TITLE: Questions
#+AUTHOR: author
#+OPTIONS: \n:t toc:nil html-postamble:nil
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength\parindent{0pt}

+ *Question 1*

stuff

*Reference:* Chapters 4 and 8 from /An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R/ which can be found at [[http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%2520Seventh%2520Printing.pdf]]

\pagebreak

+ *Q 2*
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both
x <- 1
x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: [1] 1

+ *Q3*

answer

*References:* I used the following databases to think of the most important input features
<https://stats.nba.com/players/shooting/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&sort=Corner%203%20FGM&dir=1&DistanceRange=By%20Zone&PerMode=Totals>

<http://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%2BSeason>
```

And here is the output(outputed as HTML then converted to PDF)
[image]

Here are the contents of the org file when the loading message does not appear:

```
#+TITLE: Questions
#+AUTHOR: author
#+OPTIONS: \n:t toc:nil html-postamble:nil
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \setlength\parindent{0pt}

+ *Question 1*

stuff

*Reference:* Chapters 4 and 8 from /An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R/ which can be found at [[http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%2520Seventh%2520Printing.pdf]]

#+BEGIN_SRC latex
\pagebreak
#+END_SRC

+ *Q 2*
#+begin_src R :results output :exports both
x <- 1
x
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: [1] 1

+ *Q3*

answer

*References:* I used the following databases to think of the most important input features
<https://stats.nba.com/players/shooting/?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&sort=Corner%203%20FGM&dir=1&DistanceRange=By%20Zone&PerMode=Totals>

<http://www.pbpstats.com/totals/nba/player?Season=2018-19&SeasonType=Regular%2BSeason>
```

And here is the output it produces:
[image]

Comment: Did you try setting `M-x customize-option org-html-postamble` to `No postamble`?

Comment: @Tobias I did set it to nil but nothing changed.

Comment: The question is different from what the title advertises: please fix that. You should also post the org file and the HTML file that is produced, as part of your question.

Comment: @NickD I noticed I had a \pagebreak that wasn't wrapped in #+BEGIN_SRC and #+END_SRC.  Once I wrapped it, the loading message disappeared.

Comment: Without the context, the comment is almost meaningless: we don't know what the org file looks like, so I can't tell what the connection is. As it stands, I think your question is not helping anybody: that's why I suggested the changes above.

Comment: @qq3254 You wrote: "I noticed I had a \pagebreak that wasn't wrapped in #+BEGIN_SRC and #+END_SRC. Once I wrapped it, the loading message disappeared." Might it be that you tried to set `org-html-postamble` as file-local variable above a horizontal line inserted with `C-q C-L`? That does not work. Those lines stop the search for file local variables. Maybe it is similar with pagebreaks?

Comment: @Tobias I added the contents of my org file.  However, I am not sure what you are referring to by the horizontal line inserted with `C-q C-L`

Comment: Looks like my guess was wrong. Pittyingly I cannot test with `wkhtmltopdf` since this would pull the full X server in my WSL install. I tested with `html2ps test.org > test.ps; ps2pdf test.ps test.pdf`. Viewing that pdf does not show the `Loading...` message but it also does not colorize the source blocks. Maybe, I can help you when I am on my real Linux-box tonight.